# WCF - Removing minOccurs 0 from sub-service WSDL

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service exposing a WSDL.
The service is making another call to retrieve data and return it directly without any data transformation.

In the sub-service data is returned like this :

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="identifier" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

But in the WSDL on the service, who is refered to the subservice data model, the data is different :

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="identifier" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

Why is the `minOccurs="0"` replaced by `minOccurs="1"` and how to prevent it without creating my own objects and mappers ?

Comment: There is a schema and the schema sets the min and max.  It may be the schema the service is using is a different version from the one you are using.

Comment: The <minOccurs> indicator specifies the minimum number of times an element can occur.Its value is based on the XML document.